# Ajax call to controller takes you to another page instead of just returning JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am using jQuery, a modal form - and MVC 5.

When I click ok on the modal box, the javascript below, should make an ajax call to the "Companies/Createa" controller.

It does this fine, the code runs and my database is updated - however, when returning the JSON data to the ajax call, the browser page shows the JSON data - rather than following through the javascript code, and adding the new value to the drop down list.

Line which returns the data is:

```
return Json(new { Company = dbCompany, Error = string.Empty });
```

Can anyone see why the controller is not just sending the JSON to the ajax request, instead of to the following:

[image: Screen Shot of screen after Ajax post]

I suspect it's my javascript code - but I'm trying to follow the example on asp.net's website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/adding-a-new-category-to-the-dropdownlist-using-jquery-ui

Thank you, Mark

The full controller code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Createa([Bind(Include = "CompanyId,CompanyName")] Company company)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Company.Add(company);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var dbCompany = db.Company.Where(g => g.CompanyName == company.CompanyName).SingleOrDefault();
                // **** Following line executes and sends back JSON data ****
                return Json(new { Company = dbCompany, Error = string.Empty });
            }
            else
            {
                string errMsg = "Something failed, probably validation";
                var er = ModelState.Values.FirstOrDefault();
                if (er != null && er.Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(er.Value.AttemptedValue))
                    errMsg = "\"" + er.Value.AttemptedValue + "\" Does not validate";
                return Json(new { Error = errMsg });
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
        {
            if (ioex.Message.Contains("Sequence contains more than one element"))
                return Json(new { Error = "Value provided exists in DB, enter a unique value" });
            return Json(new { Error = "Internal Error with input provided" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Error = "Internal Error with input provided" });
        }
    }
```

The jQuery/Javascript which calls the controller is:

```
$(function () {
$('#companyDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 250,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Add Company',
    buttons: {
        'Save': function () {
            alert("Save pressed");  // This alert never shows
            var createCompanyForm = $('#createCompanyForm');
            if (createCompanyForm.valid()) {
                $.post(createCompanyForm.attr('action'), createCompanyForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                    if (data.Error != '') {
                        alert("Error noted: " + data.Error);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Add the new company to the dropdown list and select it
                        $('#CompanyId').append(
                                $('<option></option>')
                                    .val(data.Company.CompanyId)
                                    .html(data.Company.CompanyName)
                                    .prop('selected', true)  // Selects the new Company in the DropDown LB
                            );
                        $('#companyDialog').dialog('close');
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

$('#companyAddLink').click(function () {
    var createFormUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    //alert(createFormUrl);
    $('#companyDialog').html('')
    .load(createFormUrl, function () {
        // The createCompanyForm is loaded on the fly using jQuery load. 
        // In order to have client validation working it is necessary to tell the 
        // jQuery.validator to parse the newly added content
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createCompanyForm');
        $('#companyDialog').dialog('open');
    });
    //alert("finished click function");
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Is it reaching to $.post callback function you provided?

Comment: Hi Vijay - you've just helped me resolve this (or at least made me realise it was not the Save button click that wasn't working - it was me pressing enter when typing into the modal box, rather than clicking the Save button - thereby triggering the forms Post, rather than programmatically through the jQuery code)!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by me pressing the Enter key, thereby triggering the Forms post - rather than me actually clicking the "Save" button on the modal form.

Silly error - but hopefully helps others.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Dont you think it is a potential bug. You should handle enter key to default action of the model popup (i.e. save)   :D

Comment: Yeah I agree - think I'll have to add some code to catch it, and ensure enter triggers the button click, rather than the form post.  Bit of a pain, but I'm off to google it now :)  Cheers Vijay